# Neural network for guessing game

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I want to implement neural network which would guess whether user will pick true or false.

What would be most appropriate design? I'm a newbie on such things, but I think of the following:

have 128 inputs, for 128 previous guesses (memory if you will).

First input is the latest guess, second is previous, third is 2 turns back and etc.

I'm thinking of having hidden fully connected layer of 256 nodes and the final single layer for the output.

This is how I'd represent my inputs: 0 - not yet guessed, 0.5 - the guess was false, 1 - the guess was true

And this is the value of the outputs: 0 is false and 1 is true (I'd convert this to input format when output becomes the input)

Now, the main fear I have with this design is that inputs are moving. That is, the first input in first guess will be second in another guess, third in another and I fear there will be no reusability and logic will be duplicated and guesses will be rock solid.

Is my fear baseless? Should I just let neural network do the thinking for me and be done with it?

I remember I saw something in youtube once for memory in neural network to feed inputs one by one. Is this the wrong way I am doing this and there's special way for having memory in neural net?

If my design is wrong what design would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you should be asking yourself why you want to use neural networks. Have you tried simpler (fewer parameters) models first, for example [Hidden Markov Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model)? Do you have enough data to be training a network beyond a couple of layer?

Assuming that you've sure that you want to use a neural network then we should start at the begin, i.e. the input. Your input is a categorical feature, so should be encoded in a way that is suitable. One common way to encode these features is [one-hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot). So in your case your inputs would look like:

```
NYG = [1, 0, 0]
T   = [0, 1, 0]
F   = [0, 0, 1]
```

Once you have your input data formated you can think about a network architecture. While there's a few ways to tackle every problem it sounds like you might want to use [Recurrent neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network), which can output a classification based on a sequence of inputs. I'd suggest starting with a couple of smallish layers (64 nodes) of LSTM cells and see how you get on, then you can think about how to grow from there (if you have enough data).

**I really can't stress enough that you shouldn't just jump into neural networks. They can be very useful, or they can add massive confusion where it's just not needed.**

Comment: I want neural networks because this is similar to how our brains work and i know for a fact that who designed our brain picked a best design thus I am not interested in any other machine learning techniques and I view them inferior.

Thanks for tips on one hot and recurrent neural nets and on the layers though, I'll go with recurrent neural net.